# Properly calculating breakage rates and their impact

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

So I'm working on calculating how breakage rates impact manufacturing. Running into a fairly interesting problem:

I have three steps in the process, A, B, and C. The process (generally, not always) goes A->B->C. Each has an associated weight with how many units end up going through each step. Let's call it A%, B%, and C%.

As an example, let's say I'm making 100k widgets. A% = 90%, B% = 80%, and C% = 100%. So A has 90k widgets go through, B has 80k widgets go through, and C has 100k widgets go through.

Now, each step has two different types of chances of breaking.

A_Full_Break%
A_Step_Break%

B_Full_Break%
B_Step_Break%

C_Full_Break%
C_Step_Break%

Now, if the item breaks in a full break %, it's sent back to go, it needs to restart the entire process over. If it just has step break %, it just needs to redo the same step.

Since A is the first step, naturally one of the two steps is 0%. An argument could be made for either one, and really, it's whatever is easier to think of it as.

Now, A, B, and C each have a Raw Equipment Capacity. Let's call it A_REC, B_REC, and C_REC. What I'm trying to figure out is what the actual capacity is. A simple example would be: If I only have one step, A_REC, and the capacity was 100k widgets, with a 10% breakage rate, I'd have a real capacity of 90k widgets, since 10k of them would break. What I'm trying to solve is, how do I calculate the real capacity of my steps, in general terms, given that some units get sent back through, break again, get sent back, could break at a different step, might break at that step but just need a redo, etc. This looks like it should be easy to calculate, but it's been driving me nuts trying to make it work.

(The actual problem I'm working on has 15 steps and a few more twists, but I think I've got a solid handle on those parts, and can extrapolate an answer...)

Comment: From your example, it seems that whenever a widget breaks, you just disregard it completely from your calculation, which makes it redundant to divide up the breaking rates into step_break and full_break. I feel like you should make it a bit more clear how you want breaking parts to influence the actual capacity.

Comment: What I mean by that is: Looking at *one* sequence of steps $A \to B \to C$, If you start with a capacity $K$, your actual capacity after one such sequence is simply $$K_\text{actual} = (1-B_A)(1-B_B)(1-B_C)K,$$ where the $B$'s are the breaking rates at every single step (so the sum of both breaking rates that you mention). However, you seem to want a more detailled answer than that, I suppose.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "real capacity."  It seems like if you start out to make $100k$ widgets, you always make $100k$ widgets, since any that break along the way are redone.  Why is the real capacity less than $100$k?   Say you have just the machine $A$ with a $10\%$ breakage rate.  What is it's real capacity?  I know that's what you say you can't calculate, but can you describe in words what it should measure?  I presume the answer you're looking for is somewhere between $90$k and $100$k, but I don't get what it's suppose to be a measure of.

Comment: So a machine could, in theory, get 100k widgets manufactured in a month if everything went perfectly. (This is already factoring out worker breaks, maintaince, shifts, etc. etc.). However, because 10% of the widgets going through the machine break, it can "actually" only get 90k widgets manufactured per month

Comment: @LukasMiristwhisky: That very well might be the total end capacity for the entire system. I'm trying to figure out what the impact on a per-system basis is. For example, if